# Travel time calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, road, route, isochrone

I will try explain this as best I can.

I have a point on a map and I want to create buffers surrounding the site; for example, 10Km, 20Km 50Km.  This is easy.  But I also need to show buffers for distance from site, based on road network. lets says 30mins, 60mins 180mins etc.

I have a detailed road network map showing the various road classes, and I could assign average speeds to them but from here... I am lost.

Is this possible in QGIS 2.6.1.

Also if I could use Googles route calculator it would be AMAZING!

Oh and I have tried the route calculator tool, but I want to put in point a, then identify max travel time, then show polygon of area.

Comment: Is [this](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/12/drive-time-isochrones/) what you're looking to do

Answer (score 6):

You can either use [pgRouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) or if not using your data but the OSM street network would be fine, use the [OSM Route](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMroute/) plugin: Enter a start point and fill out the Accessibility Analysis options.

[image: OSM Route Accessibility Analysis]

[image: Isochrones from OSM Route]

Comment: Which one do you mean? I edited the answer to show how to do it in OSM Route.

Comment: Okay this looks like what i am looking for, however, i just cant check it now, i will do so when i can.

Comment: Looks ideal, but not working!!! For OSM that is. PGrouting i cant find.

Comment: OSMroute plugin does not work since OpenRouteService API has been [changed](http://k1z.blog.uni-heidelberg.de/2017/04/29/openrouteservice-with-new-api-functions-and-look/). Check out another plugin called [OSMtools](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMtools/).

Answer (score 5):

For whoever also stumbles on this question. Now for more than 2 years since the inital question was raised and QGis 3.X has become more mature, one could achieve this by [ORS tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ORStools/) or [QNEAT3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QNEAT3/)

- ORS tools uses the Open Route Services API (online) and has some
  limitations
- QNEAT3 can be used for offline/own network files

Comment: Thank you! I stumbled onto this and went looking for OSM Routes only to find it depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest you the isochrone solution I've just developed: https://github.com/punkerpunker/isochrone. It might be interesting for you, works out of the box and solves task you've mentioned.